# Самообучение нам не нужно!

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, удаление-метки

Предлагаю убрать метку [самообучение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Она не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки. Все вопросы на СО так или иначе уже направлены на самообучение.

Comment: Там всего 21 вопрос. Надо просто пробежаться по ним. Тем более есть метка [tag:обучение]

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а для каких вопросов метка обучение? может и ее заодно того?

Comment: we don't need no education!